# React-Native Button above on keyboard

Tags: react-native

I want to make button when keyboard is appeared like these pictures below

[image]

when TextInput is clicked, Button is appeared with keyboard
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 render(){
       return(
           <>
              <View>
                  ... <Text> and <TextInput>
              </View>
              <Button >
           </>
       )
    }
```